# Let {$a_n$}$=(3- \frac{1}{n^2},n\sin(\frac{2}{n}))$. Prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=(3,2)$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

i have a problem solving this limit by definition.

**Limit:**  In $(R^2,d_2)$ 
Let {$a_n$}$=(3- \frac{1}{n^2},n\sin(\frac{2}{n}))$,
 Prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=(3,2)$

**I try this:**

> Let $\epsilon >0$
>   
>  Take $N= ...$
>   
>  If $n>N$ then:
>   
>  $d_2(a_n,L)=d_2((3-\frac{1}{n^2},n\sin(\frac{2}{n}),(3,2))=((3-\frac{1}{n^2}-3)^2+(n\sin(\frac{2}{n})-2)^2)^{1/2}$

Note: $d_2((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=((x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2)^{1/2}$

I'm very stuck with this proof. Can someone help me?

Comment: What is <br> in the question?

Comment: Nothing. Is an error @mathiu_lady

Comment: Then delete it..@bvss12

Answer (score 3):

Note that a sequence $((x_n,y_n))$ converges to $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ if and only if $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$.

Certainly $3-1/n^2\to 3$, so it remains to show $n\sin(2/n)\to 2$. Since $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin(2/n)=2\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(2/n)}{2/n}=2.
$$